# When did 'permission' become popular as a therapy term

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

Permission has several uses, but somewhere around the 1990s it became common to hear it in the context of therapy sessions as in "you need to give yourself permission to..." do this or that. When did this happen?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the history of psychotherapy, not English.

Comment: That's ridiculous. It's about the history of that particular slang term, when it became popular.  Great question!

Comment: There is an entire lexicon of therapy language which merges into mainstream conversation.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear to have started taking off circa 1970—surprise, surprise. See [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=give%20yourself%20permission%2Bgive%20myself%20permission%2Bgive%20herself%20permission%2Bgive%20himself%20permission&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) for “give myself/yourself/herself/himself permission.”